# noun-modifier word order in 'date certain'

Tags: expressions, legalese

One will occasionally hear the term `date certain` (meaning 'a fixed, definite date') in legal or business contexts. e.g.,

> The Courts have continually emphasized that the Act demands primary NAAQS achievement by a date certain.

How long ago does this usage date to and how did it get its unusual word order? (I am guessing a calque from French). I have made good faith efforts to learn the answer by myself, documented [here](http://bit.ly/LJZ7Iv), with no success.

Comment: Our English heritage of Law French rears its ugly tête yet again.

Answer (score 1):

This subject generally is covered in David Mellinkoff's book, *The Language of the Law*. English law was written in a combination of English and French (called 'law French' as noted in the comment above) until the 17th century.

If you look at the texts published by the Selden Society you will find many examples of this usage. I do not know if they are online or not. Somewhere there is a web site which prints ancient English court decisions on a daily basis; you will find other examples there. This leads into a discussion of why you say, "cease and desist" rather than just "cease"; or "to have and to hold" rather than just "possess", but that question wasn't asked.